# Is the "money" tag valuable?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there value in the [money](https://money.stackexchange.com/tags/money) tag?  Should we delete the tag all together?  When should you use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a meaning of "currency" would be appropriate in a handful of cases, but most of the usages are inappropriate.

I support deleting the tag, so I will do that now -- you'll have a few [untagged](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions to retag at that point, and I suggest [currency](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency) as a possible alternative.

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out - I took care of the untagged questions.